# Convergence of a sequence of random variables in probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

This is a problem from K.L. Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory". I have been asked to prove by giving an example that if a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ converges to $0$ in probability then $\frac{S_n}{n}$ may not converge to $0$ in probability (where $\{S_n\}$ denotes the partial sum sequence).

I have started with the sequence (as per the hint given) $\{X_n\}$ such that $X_n$ assumes values $2^n$ and $0$ with probabilities $\frac{1}{n}$ and $1-\frac{1}{n}$ respectively. It is easy to show that this sequence converges to $0$ in probability. However I am not being able to prove that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ doesn't converge to $0$ in probability. Can someone give a hint or a direction to proceed in?

Comment: Show that $\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n}{n}\leq 1)$ does not converge to zero by observing that $\frac{S_n}{n}\leq 1$ implies that $X_i=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: @Jeff but how does $\frac{S_n}{n}\leq 1$ imply that $X_i=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$? Suppose $X_1$ assumes the value $2$ and $X_2$ and $X_3$ assume values $0$ each. Then $\frac{S_3}{3}=\frac{2}{3}<1$. I might be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Two more points. Firstly, probability of $X_i=0$ for every $i\leq n$ is $\prod_{i\leq n} (1-\frac{1}{i})=\prod_{i\leq n} (\frac{i-1}{i})=\frac{1}{n}$ which converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Secondly, what to do by showing probability of $\frac{S_n}{n}\leq 1$ doesn't converge to $0$? We have to show that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ doesn't converge to $0$, that is probability of $\frac{S-n}{n}>\text{ something}$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: Convergence in probability to zero means that $P(S_n/n > \varepsilon)$ converges to zero for all $\varepsilon$. If you show that for some $\varepsilon>0$ the probability does not converge to zero, then $S/n$ does not converge to zero in probability. So if you show that $P(S_n/n < \varepsilon)$ converges to zero for some $\varepsilon$, then you're done.

Comment: The argument has to be changed slightly from my initial comments. If $S_n/n\leq 1$ then $X_i=0$ for all $i$ with $2^i \geq n$, which is nearly all of the indices when $n$ is large (but you are correct, not all of them).

Comment: @Jeff that is the point. I cannot make this "when $n$ is large" part rigorous. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show that $\frac{S_n}{n}$ doesn't converge to $0$ in probability. For this, it is enough to show that $\mathcal{P}\{\frac{S_n}{n}\geq 1\}=\mathcal{P}\{S_n\geq n\}>C$ for some positive constant $C$ independent of $n$ (or at least for every $n$ greater than some fixed natural number). For this, we note that if $S_n<n$ holds then $X_i=0$ for each $i>\log_2 n$, because, if $S_n<n$, then the sum cannot consist of terms bigger than $n$. This and the fact that the $X_i$'s are independent random variables, together imply that
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{P}\big\{S_n<n\big\}\leq\mathcal{P}\big\{X_i=0:\log_2 n<i\leq n\big\}=\prod\limits_{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil}^n\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{i}\Bigg)=\frac{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}{n}.
\end{equation*}
The right-hand term converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. We can see this by computing the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log_2 x -1}{x}$. The expression being in $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminate form, we can apply l'Hopital's rule to write
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log_2 x -1}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln 2}=0
\end{align*}
Thus we see that $\mathcal{P}\{S_n<n\}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus if we choose $C=0.5$, say, then there exists a natural number $N_0$ such that for all natural numbers $n\geq N_0$, $\mathcal{P}\{S_n<n\}<C$, or in other words $\mathcal{P}\{S_n\geq n\}>1-C=1-0.5=0.5=C$ which is exactly what we wanted to show. Hence $\frac{S_n}{n}$ does not converge to $0$ in probability. Hope that helps.

Comment: That was quite a brilliant answer. I was beating about the bush. Thanks for helping.